# Recurrence relation for hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions

Are there known recurrence relations of the hypergeometric function with the structure:

$$x{}_2F_1(a,b,c,x)=\sum_{n=1}^m c_n {}_2F_1(a+n,b-n,c,x)?$$

I have been looking around for a while, but I couldn't find anything